# Solution to the initial value problem $ty''-ty'-2y=3$ using Laplace transforms.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

The problem is as follows:

> Solve the initial value problem using the method of Laplace transforms
>   $$ty''-ty'-2y=3$$
>   $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=-1$.

I have attempted this question but to no avail. I have used the formula $\mathcal{L}(ty'')=-F''(s)$ to start. Eventually getting an equation whereby I need to integrate to obtain $Y(s)$. Then using the Laplace inverse function but it does not get the correct answer. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $Y={\cal L}(y)$ then with
$${\cal L}(ty'')=-\Big[s^2Y-sy(0)-y'(0)\Big]'$$
$${\cal L}(ty')=-\Big[sY-y(0)\Big]'$$
you will find the equation 
$$Y'+\dfrac{2s+3}{s^2+s}Y=\dfrac{2s-3}{s^2(s+1)}$$
which is a first order differential equation.